# Python Get Key/Value from Dynamic List

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using argparse to pull in additional arguments to my script.

I can get the keys and values from the additional arguments like so if one argument is passed:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My app.')
parser.add_argument('-n', '--project-name', required=False, default='test')
args, remaining_argv = parser.parse_known_args()
set_config(remaining_argv[0], remaining_argv[1]
```

But I want to be able to set keys and values with a dynamic list. I can get the number of arguments by dividing by 2 but I need to step thru the array to set key and value:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My app.')
parser.add_argument('-n', '--project-name', required=False, default='test')
args, remaining_argv = parser.parse_known_args()
number_of_additional_arguments = int(len(remaining_args)/2)
for r in range(0,number_of_additional_arguments):
   key = ??
   value = ??
   set_config(key, value)
```

How can I set the keys and values dynamically?

Comment: How are the pairs written?   `myscript.py -n mytest foo 1 bar 2 baz 3`, or maybe `myscript.py -n mytest --foo=1 --bar=2 --baz=3`, or something else.  `remaining_argv` is a list of strings.  How you parse that list depends on the input you expect.  `argparse` has not modified this unparsed part of `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to just "encode" the key-value pairs in some format. For example, comma separated. If you can do that you don't need `parse_known_args` and can instead use `parse_args` with the `nargs='+'` setting. Here is a small example:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="My app.")
parser.add_argument("keyvals", type=str, nargs="+", help="Key value pairs")


args = parser.parse_args()

for keyval in list(args.keyvals):
    key, val = keyval.split(",")
    print(f"key: {key}, val: {val}")
```

Calling this script produces the following output:

```
> python3 argparse_question.py a,b c,d e,f
key: a, val: b
key: c, val: d
key: e, val: f
```

Comment: Great solution!